# Call-time pass-by-reference pickle

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

Got ourselves in a bit of a pickle.  Our host has upgraded php to 5.4 and we're still running some code (we didn't write) in a class that passes arguments to a function by reference and it looks like this:

```
$func_args = '';

// Make $row[0], $row[1] accessible by using $C1, $C2 etc.
foreach ($row as $k => $v)
{
    ${'C'.($k+1)} = $v;

    $func_args .= "&\$C".($k+1).",";
}

// Give the user a chance to tweak the results with any function of their choice
// tweak functions are registered with $ez_results->register_function('func_name');
if ( is_array($this->tweak_functions) )
{
    // Tweak results with each registered function
    foreach ( $this->tweak_functions as $tweak_function )
    {
        // If function C1, C2, etc exists then run it
        if ( function_exists($tweak_function) )
        {
            eval("$tweak_function(".substr($func_args,0,-1).");");
        }
    }
}
```

functions are registered further in the class here:

```
var $tweak_functions = array('tweak_results');

function register_function($function_name)
{
    $this->tweak_functions[] = $function_name;
}
```

The functions are defined on external PHP files like this:

```
function results_manipulation($news_id,$news_name,$news_seoname,$news_date2,$news_summary,$news_article,$news_url,$image_name,$image_thumb,$news_categories)
{
    global $i;

    if(!empty($image_thumb) && $i < 3 && empty($_GET['pg']) ){
        $image_thumb = '<div class="newsthumb" style="background-image:url('.$image_thumb.')" title="'.$image_name.'"></div>';
    }else{
        $image_thumb = '';
    }

    $i++;
}
```

I've looked at a lot of similar questions and tried to find a way of replacing the code and keeping everything working but without any success.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Comment: I can upload the full class if that would help.

Comment: That's some pretty horrible code... What the first part is really trying to do is a simple `call_user_func_array`, there's no need for the `eval` call and cobbling together of strings. The question is, can those functions it's calling work without reference-at-calltime? Supposedly they should, so just removing the `&` should do the trick.

Comment: Pretty horrible I know deceze and I'll be honest I've been meaning to rewrite it for ages (probably 18 months) but the problem became a real issue overnight when php5.4 was rolled out - I should have seen it coming!  The code is being used on a fair number of sites so I sort of need a quick solution and to give me breathing space to go back and create a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up completely re-writing the function and updating all websites with the re-written code.

Thanks to all who offered suggestions ultimately though reworking what we had was just prolonging the pain: at some stage a full re-write would have been required.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the signature of all of your tweak functions to include the reference notation on the argument list and drop it from the argument list.

```
  function someTweakFunction(&$a, &$b, &$c);
```

Also it would be a good thing if you can remove the eval code. In this particular case it doesn't appear to be dangerous but it is also unneeded. You can use call_user_func_array instead.

When you build you argument list create an array of arguments instead of a string of them.

```
$func_args = array();

// Make $row[0], $row[1] accessible by using $C1, $C2 etc.
foreach ($row as $k => $v)
{
    $func_args[] = &$v;
}
if ( is_array($this->tweak_functions) )
{
    // Tweak results with each registered function
    foreach ( $this->tweak_functions as $tweak_function )
    {
        // If function C1, C2, etc exists then run it
        if ( function_exists($tweak_function) )
        {
            call_user_func_array($tweak_function, $func_args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Orangepill - thanks so much for responding.  I've tried the changes above and while there is no longer a fatal error the arguments in $tweak_function don't appear to be manipulated at all. i.e. $image_thumb in my example use above just spits out the database value (path to image).  Not sure where i've gone wrong?

Comment: @Studio4 did you make sure to change the method signature to change it to accept the arguments by reference?

Comment: I did indeed - I'm actually only using one function "results_manipulation" so in my example above I added an ampersand to each argument. When running the change it came up blank so I added the following line before $func_args[] = &$v; .... ${'C'.($k+1)} = $v; that gave me some output but it didn't process the individual changes.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem (using ez_results), and I solved it. Maybe somebody will fond this useful.

This line

```
//old    
$func_args .= "&\$C".($k+1).",";
```

change to:

```
//new
$func_args .= "\$C".($k+1).",";
```

Also, the function you used with ezr->register_function("my_function")

```
//old
my_function($arg1, $arg2, $arg3...)
```

has to be altered (add '&' in front of every argument):

```
//new
my_function(&$arg1, &$arg2, &$arg3...)
```